# importing a dataframe stored in R into rattle

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is slightly ambiguous, I guess it reflects my naivety in this area. There may be multiple solutions or a 'better' way of approaching it. Open to all ideas.

Say I have imported a csv file `f` into R and after making some modifications to the corresponding dataframe I have a new dataframe `df`. How can I then import `df` into Rattle? Would it be easier to instead import the file `f` into Rattle and then make the changes in Rattle to obtain `df`.

Comment: Why not to save the result (df ) in a csv?

Comment: see comment to iTech's answer.

Comment: Whay do are u using rattle?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save your modified dataframe `df` to a new CSV file and import it in Rattle. Here is an example:

```
write.csv(df,file="myfile.csv")
```

You can also you `write.table` if you want more control on the output file format

Comment: ok, cheers. was just hoping there was a way of doing it with out this intermediate step.